# MEAN stack hangs on localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, localhost, mean-stack

I am trying to implement the MEAN stack using the [BitNami](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_MEAN_Stack_%28MongoDB,_Express,_Angular,_Node.js%29) version. I ran into some errors with the `mean-stack-todo` demo app - so I decided to build it from scratch(ish) by running `express xxx` in the terminal, and running `npm install`. Then I used `bower` (with the `.bowerrc` file) to install `angular`, `angular-bootstrap`, and `jquery` into the `/public/javascripts/vendor` folder. I then went about creating all the files - and making necessary changes to the code. I got to the point where I could go to `localhost:3000` and see the page - but there were errors in the console. One of them had to do with index.js (which I had forgotten to change to the version I wanted - it wasn't finding a .json file that was supposed to be in the root directory of the site, because my index.js file was wrong). After making the necessary changes - I can no longer see the page, and my browser hangs on `localhost:3000` - it never loads. Here is my index.js file, the problem has to be here (at least partially) because the problem started happening right after I changed it.

routes/index.js

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(Member) {
  return function(req, res) {
    Member.find({}, function(error, members) {
      res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express',
        members : members
      });
    });
  };
};

exports.addMember = function(Member) {
  return function(req, res) {
    var member = new Member(req.body);
    member.save(function(error, member) {
      if (error || !member) {
        res.json({ error : error });
      } else {
        res.json({ member : member });
      }
    });
  };
};

exports.get = function(Member) {
  return function(req, res) {
    Member.find({}, function(error, members) {
      res.json({ members : members });
    });
  }
};

exports.update = function(Member) {
  return function(req, res) {
    Member.findOne({ _id : req.params.id }, function(error, member) {
      if (error || !member) {
        res.json({ error : error });
      } else {
        member.done = req.body.done;
        member.save(function(error, member) {
          if (error || !member) {
            res.json({ error : error });
          } else {
            res.json({ member : member });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Here is another possibly relevant tidbit - when I run `node app`, I see:

```
connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
```

Let me know if you see anything - or need to see any other files. The last error I was getting was that it couldnt find `localhost:3000/members.json` (but the page was being displayed). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling the mean-stack-todo app and fixing the error. It was something to do with favicon.ico - and I had to change an `app.use(express.favicon());` to `app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));`. I also had to copy `favicon.ico` into the `public` folder.